# How make a spawnpoint in Unity 2D?

Tags: 3d

I want to create a spawnpoint so that the player always appears where the spawnpoint is when I start the game. I am working in Unity C# 2D. Thanks in advance for your reply.

I need to create a single spawnpoint for player spawn and respawn. I will be grateful...

Answer (score 0):

Create a script : SpawnPlayer wich contains a transform position.
Then, you'll just need a condition when this script will be used.

```
public class SpawnPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform spawnPoint;
    
    public void Spawn()
    {
        transform.position = spawnPoint.position;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to put a transform in your inspector right [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGeNF.png) and your SpawnPoint need to be an Empty Object, whatever your want, just drag and drop your object on your script to get this transform.

Of course, put Spawn() into your Start() method, or into another method called, depends of what you need to do.

Comment: player is missing

Comment: I need more info, this script needs to be a component on your player in the hierarchy, so player can't be missing, then you create an empty point wich will be your spawnPoint and at this point you drag an drop in the hierarchy your spawnPoint object